# OpenRailway Map basemap in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap, basemap

I'm a bit of a QGIS noob when it comes to anything other than the basics so hoping someone has an easy solution to this. I am trying to use Open Railway Maps ( https://www.openrailwaymap.org/ ) as a basemap for a project and have had no success following multiple guides. I tried the method recommended in the wiki ( https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRailwayMap/API#Usage_in_QGIS ) and this guide https://www.xyht.com/spatial-itgis/using-openstreetmap-basemaps-qgis-3-0/ . I have attached a screenshot of the result, it seems to only be displaying a segment of the map, I feel like this is probably some projection issue. 
What can I do to sort this out?
[image]

Comment: Looks like your 'BRD Nikos' is projected (meters) - it will need to be in WGS84 for your data to overlay OSM/ORW tiles. see answer - do you have a link to that BR Nikos file?

Comment: I'll post a zip of the files if the problems persist, once I got the open rail maps basemap to load it seems to be all overlaying properly.

Answer (score 2):

You will need OpenStreetMap tiles underneath the OpenRailWay tiles

you can use xyz tiles in QGIS

OpenRailway tile sets

```
https://a.tiles.openrailwaymap.org/standard/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

OpenStreetMap tiles

```
http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

To get this in QGIS:

[image]

Comment: Interestingly now the Open Rail Maps shows up but the OSM basemap does not...not sure what the reason for that would be? But either way I can substitute another reference basemap easily enough, so thanks for getting the important bit working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install featured [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) plugin.
2. Open search pane and print `openrailwaymap`
3. Push `Add` button
4. In search pane print `Mapnik`
5. Push `Add` button.

Expected result without printing magic urls are in screenshot below.

[image]